# Как объединить данные из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы

**Hero**

| id | name | universe_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Mark | 1 |
| 99 | Glume | 1 |

**Universe**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Andromeda |
| 2 | Aurora |

Как вернуть таблицу **Hero, но вместо `universe_id` поставить **universe->name**? Новичок в MySql поэтому сложно мне разобраться.

Попробовал что-то вроде этого

```
exports.getHero = (req, res) => {

const sql = "SELECT * FROM `hero` JOIN `universe` WHERE `id`=`universe_id` ON `hero.universe_id`=`universe.id`";
    db.query(sql, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            response.returnSingleValue(results, res);
        }
    });
};
```

Не сработало.

Также попробовал этот код

```
SELECT `hero`.`id`, `hero`.`name`, `universe`.`name`
FROM `hero`
JOIN `universe` ON `hero`.`universe_id` = `universe`.`id`
```

Тоже не правильно работает.

Ожидаемый результат

```
[{
  id: 12, 
  name: Mark,
  universe_id: Andromeda
},
{
  id: 99, 
  name: Glume,
  universe_id: Andromeda
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const sql = "SELECT h.id, h.name, u.name as universe_id FROM `hero` as h LEFT JOIN `universe` as u ON h.universe_id=u.id";
```

Про джоины: https://shra.ru/2017/09/sql-join-v-primerakh-s-opisaniem/

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ. Я вечером проверю и приму :)

Comment: Тут тоже напиши ответ, я приму и его. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71788081/how-to-get-relation-table-data-name-instead-of-id